# Multiple tasks in a week

Tags: emacs, org-mode

How do I specify a task in org-mode as needing to be done 3 times a week without being specific about which day of the week it is?

Org-mode documentation for repeated tasks suggests the use of y/m/d/h intervals, but I didn't find the syntax for specifying an event n times per interval.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define your TODO as a habit in org:

> The TODO may also have minimum and maximum ranges specified by
>        using the syntax `.+2d/3d', which says that you want to do the
>        task at least every three days, but at most every two days.

Maybe this would serve your purpose?

Comment: I think its good enough for me at the moment. Thanks for reminding me of that feature in org-mode.